# CoreGraphics: can't render a color PDF

Tags: core-graphics, quartz-2d

I'm rendering a PDF with the following code as a test:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  @autoreleasepool {

    NSURL* theFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"test.pdf"];

    CGContextRef pdfContext = CGPDFContextCreateWithURL((CFURLRef) theFile, nil, nil);

    CGColorSpaceRef rgb = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    assert(CGColorSpaceGetNumberOfComponents(rgb) == 3);
    CGContextSetFillColorSpace(pdfContext,rgb);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorSpace(pdfContext, rgb);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(rgb);

    CGPDFContextBeginPage(pdfContext, nil);

    CGFloat rgba[4] = {0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0};
    CGContextSetFillColor(pdfContext, rgba);
    CGContextFillRect(pdfContext, CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100));

    CGPDFContextEndPage (pdfContext);
    CGContextRelease (pdfContext);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I would expect the box to be cyan, but the output is black.

Answer (score 0):

Move `CGPDFContextBeginPage(pdfContext, nil);` up above the colour space stuff. I think your colour space modifications are being quietly discarded because you haven't started a page. Thanks, CoreGraphics!